# Obtain UserName and Password from Online Text File

Tags: vb.net, authentication, passwords

I have the following code:

```
Dim userName As String
Dim passWord As String

'
' Populate userName and passWord from an online text file ...
'

If textbox1.text = userName AndAlso Textbox2.text = passWord Then
    MsgBox("Welcome")
Else 
    MsgBox("UserName or Password incorrect")
End If
```

How do I verify the user and password against an online text file from a URL that contains data like:

```
User;Password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class methods - `DownloadFile` or `DownloadString` or `DownloadData` to read the URL.

EDIT: Use String.Split() method to separate username and password.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
 Dim wc As New WebClient 
 Dim strings As String 
 strings = wc.DownloadString("weebly.com/uploads/9/5/8/9/9589176/passwords.txt";) 
 wc.Dispose() 

 Dim ar() as String = strings.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
 IF ar(0)=TextBox1.Text and ar(1)=TextBox2.Text Then 
   MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "Welcome", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) 
   Form2.Show() 
 Else 
   MsgBox("Wrong Password Try Again") 
 End If 
End Sub
```